# Twitter Academic Full Archive search bearer token stopped working

Tags: twitter, archive, tweets

I used to have an academic license for twitter.
I have heard that it is possible that X will abandon this, however, it still appears in the documentation.

Last time I used my academic bearer token for full archive search was in June 2023.
Today, in October 2023 it is not working.

Are academic licenses officially over, or is it possible to redeem it? Documentation and links provided by X did not help me, even though I spent a lot of time trying to figure out if there is a link for support, or to apply.

I renewed the token, but it didn't help.
I created a project to connect my app, selecting academic research as an option. I clarify that I am talking about an existing app which was functional in June 2023.
I tried using the postman API, besides my existing python code (which I was using for url requests)